# PHP date() returns epoch when I pass null as the second parameter

Tags: php, date

I was wondering why PHP is giving me an epoch time when I manually pass null as the second parameter to the date function, do any of you guys know?

```
print_r(date('Y-m-d', null));
```

Result:

```
1970-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the date function is the optional timestamp.  If you specify it, that is what it will convert in the date format you request.

Since PHP doesn't use strict typing, it implements what they call `type juggling` which is described on [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).  This principles will cause your `null` value to become 0, which will represent the time of Unix epoch.

An easy way to see that is by running `var_dump((int) null);`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `date('Y-m-d')` instead of `date('Y-m-d', null)`

Becuase:

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

second parameter is timestamp and its optional, it will automatically take time() as default you dont need to set null.

If you pass null, it will not accept it as it need time stamp as value. so its giving you wrong date

Comment: I know I can do that, but I need to use this in a function for testing purposes, hence, the manual null.

Comment: By passing null you are _changing_ the timestamp used from `time()` to 0.